# Duda sobre la seguridad en la funcionalidad del código

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy realizando un `INSERT` en una base de datos pero para eso primero busco mi usuario para poder insertarlo en la base de datos.

tengo el código y si me funciona, pero lo que quiero saber si es correcto lo que estoy realizando o puede tener alguna consecuencia en la seguridad del sitio.

```
<?PHP
$id = $_POST['id']; 
$auditado = $_POST['auditado'];
$estado = "Abierto";
//conexion con Base de datos
require 'conexion.php';
include 'header.php';

session_start();
$usuario = $_SESSION["usuario"];

$query = "SELECT user_name,Posicion FROM login WHERE user_name = '$usuario'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($conexion,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
//ahora recorremos los datos texto, id que estan vinculadas a la cuenta seleccionada
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $Auditor = $row["user_name"];
                $Posicion = $row["Posicion"];
            }
```

Comment: Podrías dar un pequeño vistazo a http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Antonio , añadí una respuesta espero que siga los pasos que detallo en la misma para que mejore la seguridad de su código y recuerde siempre seguir esa idea , utilizar sentencias preparadas. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puede que el código funcione correctamente, pero tal y como está tiene graves problemas de seguridad al concatenar directamente los valores a su `query` que se puede prestar para ataques muy comunes como la Inyección SQL, que se detalla en [esta pregunta.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php).

Para ayudar a mitigar un poco estos fallos, **debería** utilizar [sentencias preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) ya sea por las extensiones `MySQLi` o `PDO`.

Siguiendo esto , su ejemplo podría quedar de la siguiente forma, *(modifiqué el estilo procedimientos por estilo orientado a objetos)* , Ojo que mi respuesta asume que obtendrá un solo registro, caso contrario , será necesario un `while`

```
session_start();
$usuario = $_SESSION["usuario"];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "basededatos");

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_name,Posicion FROM login WHERE user_name = ?")) {
    // bindeamos el parámetro con la variable de sessión
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$usuario);
    $stmt->execute();
    //vincular las variables del select
    $stmt->bind_result($Auditor, $Posicion);
    // obtener los valores 
    if($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $Auditor;
        echo $Posicion;
    }
    else{
        echo "No Hay resultados";
    }
}
```